# How to get latest artifact from artifactory?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, artifactory, wget

I have artifacts in JFrog.

Example:

https://test.com/artifactory/users/data-config/1.0.0/user.json
https://test.com/artifactory/users/data-config/1.0.1/user.json
https://test.com/artifactory/users/data-config/2.0.0/user.json

Is there a way I can download the latest version using curl? Like in this case it will be

https://test.com/artifactory/users/data-config/2.0.0/user.json

Comment: ex: https://newbedev.com/how-to-download-the-latest-artifact-from-artifactory-repository  Research it, you will see lots of similar.

Comment: @Nic3500 The files are not maven based so not sure how we can use artifactory apis.

Comment: In this example, it downloads maven files.  But the concept remains the same if they are other artifacts.  Artifactory can store anything.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment that the files are not maven based, I assume it is deployed to a generic repository and irrespective of the file type, the only way to resolve the file via direct cURL is using the following command.

```
curl -u<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -O "http://<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/artifactory/generic-repository/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"
```

So, the target path name should be given completely when it is being resolved via direct download (API). i.e., The complete target file name manually.

However, for other package types such as a maven release or a snapshot, the available options are described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact).
What are a few other additional options available?
[Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout)
, [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties)